# Access the controls from a web page

Tags: asp.net, web, external, html

I want to access the content(controls) on an external web page

1. http://nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/search.misc
   There are a few controls there like the text box, get the value of it,
2. redirect to http://nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/saveSearchSub.misc 
   supplying necessary input

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code based on WebClient

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("http://nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/saveSearchSub.misc");
//it's also possible to use DownloadString
string webData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
```

And so you can parse webData in order to get your wished value

Comment: This Surely answered the first question. Thank you Candie

Comment: I'am happy to help you Harish